# get html source code of external web site with php

Tags: php, dom, curl, ganon

im try different some class  to get DOM of external site like below but it's not work .

class's i try :

```
ganon.php
simple_html_dom.php
Curl
```

website:

```
http://en.tsetmc.com/loader.aspx?ParTree=121C1412&inscode=65883838195688438
```

below site do it correctly

```
http://www.serversfree.com/free-seo-tools/view-source-code/
```

Answer (score 0):

First: Make sure that the server is allowed to access ALL pages on the Internet

Example for Ganon:
include_once('ganon.php');
$doc = file_get_dom('http://www.google.com');

Your other link do not work. Make sure, your link ist correct.

You could try using echo file_get_contents ("http://www.google.com) to determine whether the page can be read.

---

I do not have enough reputations for comment. Our server administrator locked various external sites that were accessible from my client. The question is old - that's why I still want to reply, because I had a similar problem. My problem was the security censorship of the server